# BidWon event is not being fired

Tags: prebid.js, prebid

We have implemented prebid.js for video using Ad server approach. We found out that the `bidWon` event is not being fired after getting the ad from DFP. We were told there is no `bidWon` callback for in-stream video with ad Server, but I could not find any document that confirms such statement.

Comment: Looks like this is expected, prebid won't callback bidWon when its video ad server approach. 

from Prebid Git hub
Confirmed. Recall that it's the video player that's making the DFP call and receiving the DFP response. Prebid.js isn't in the loop there so can't detect events.

FWIW - we do plan on taking a cut at video events, probably next quarter. That will involve modifying the VAST stored by Prebid Server. Keep an eye on the issues spaces.